# Expect script problems

Tags: tcl, telnet, expect, cisco

I am new to expect and i was using a logic to automate diconnecting telnet session where user is logged in and leave other lines as it is:

```
for {set i 0} {$i ==4} {incr i} {  
send "clear line vty $i\r"  
"confirm]" {send "\r"}  
"% Not allowed" {send "quit\r"; exit}  
}
```

it disconnects all the lines

now i use "show user" command but it's hard for me to write a script around it, the output is not friendly enough for me.so i wrote IF statements in this for loop but it was not good and not even deserving to include here. please can somebody guide me in order to how to match strings in a output result and on the basis of the strings decide to clear line or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an interesting spin on the algorithm...  the problem you currently have with iterating through all the lines is that your script as-written will exit if it merely sees itself on one of the lines...

```sh
for {set i 0} {$i == 4} {incr i} {
send "clear line vty $i\r"
"confirm]" {send "\r"}
"% Not allowed" {send "quit\r"; exit}
}
```

If you see `% Not allowed`, simply bypass this line and move to the next, instead of exiting the script...

```sh
for {set i 0} {$i < 4} {incr i} {
    send "clear line vty $i\r"
    expect {
        "confirm]" { send "\r"; expect "*#" }
        "% Not allowed" { send "! refusing to clear line vty $i\r"; expect "*#" }
    }
}
```

Cisco IOS considers a line as a comment if it begins with `!`

---

The following script logs in and clears all lines except the line the script runs on... This runs fine in my lab.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn telnet 172.16.1.5
set user [lindex $argv 0]
set pass [lindex $argv 1]

expect "Username: "
send "$user\r"
expect "assword: "
send "$pass\r"
expect ">"
send "enable\r"
expect "assword: "
send "$pass\r"
expect "*#"
for {set i 0} {$i < 5} {incr i} {
    send "clear line vty $i\r"
    expect {
            "confirm]" { send "\r"; expect "*#" }
            "% Not allowed" { send "! refusing to clear line vty $i\r"; expect "*#" }
    }
}
exit
```

Comment: i couldn't understand what is expect {} doing?? does it bring bunch of expect togather??

Comment: It is a way of telling expect to look for one of a couple of responses

Comment: ok great and one other thing...i am running an expect script to run a command to check a tty line occupied after 10 min start of lab using "sh line tty 1 sum" and then matching strings...is it possible that If their is no one on the line i can somehow return a value in my php script so that i can delete that users credentials ???

Comment: i hope you know what am i doing with all this :) Its a free cisco + cloud based network monitoring tool in a lab :) I will tell you once it's build. You are a true help

Comment: You're most welcome.  If this solves your problem, please don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: i am again using expect script and logging in to terminal server...i am using command "sh line tty $i sum" in a loop to see the results...the result shows "U for a user" and "- for no reverse telnet"...so i will read the strings and on that will delete DB entries from php

Comment: Mike Pennington.....The script you have written is not working as intended..i dont know what is wrong but it doesnt clear lines at all...the snippet from my script clear all and yours doesnt clear any :P what can be the problem????

Comment: I fixed one broken loop condition, which also existed in your original.

Comment: awesome...i have another question and i have asked it in a question but no one has answered it yet...Can i know if i have a statement like: expect {quotes*U*end-quotes}...and if it's true then return a value to php script?? Please see my other question for details...thanks